# AWS single page app and microservice use case

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I am building a basic crud web app and I want to deploy it to AWS. I read about many services only at a high, but before I implemented anything I wanted to know if the following plan was feasible and at least *somewhat* efficient:

1. Deploy the static content of a (React) Single Page Application to an S3 bucket. My plan is to use an S3 bucket to serve this static content with a custom domain name.
2. Deploy an API (that performs crud operations) using API Gateway and Lambda. This API will interact with DynamoDB for storage. This API is expected to only be used by my single page app so my assumption is that I can secure it and make it "non-public".

My understanding is that the above is a relatively cost efficient architecture for aws (though I expect to remain in the free tier).

Any major holes in my plan or something I overlooked? I know I could choose a million ways to do this including Elastic Beanstalk, but I would appreciate any advice on any different ways this can be achieved, as well as any insight on the trade offs I can make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's generally how serverless architecture work at AWS. There can be many other service used (often Cognito, CloudFront, Step Functions) and architectures implemented specific to individual use case.

A good start and  overview of serverless architectures are the following two **AWS white papers**:

- [Serverless Application Lens](https://d1.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/architecture/AWS-Serverless-Applications-Lens.pdf)
- [Serverless Architectures with AWS Lambda - Overview and Best Practices](https://d1.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/serverless-architectures-with-aws-lambda.pdf)

Based on your description, serverless way seems as the most appropriate. There are some things to consider however, and your description lucks many details. The general things to note are:

- lambda functions can only execute for **max 15 minutes**, with **limited** ram and local storage. If you expect your app to do some heavy stuff (e.g. image processing) lambdas may be the wrong choice.
- serverless architecture give you limited **control over underlying operating system**. Again, depending what your app is going to do, may need to use something that gives your full control over underlying environment.
- **testing and debugging** can be challenging especially you your serverless architecture grows. Then new services, such as X-Ray have to be used.